# PNG not found on Heroku / Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

PNG Files not loading after deploy on Heroku!

I am deploying a project on Heroku, and all assets run perfectly, including images (jpgs, jpegs and gifs), but PNG files are not load! In general pages showing:

`GET damainname.com/assets/namespace/my_image-867450b295e2051d381123c16c51548e.png 404 (Not Found)`

Other image file extensions (JPG, JPEG and GIF) load normally.

I am using:

- Heroku cedar (testing with and without assets:precompile locally)
- ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
- Rails 3.2.11

production.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['application.css', 'application.js', 'admin.css', 'admin.js']
config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: What is the entire filename of the .png asset you're missing, including capitalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things to check.

1. Do you have a `.slugingore` file in your repo?  If so, ensure there is not an entry in it like `*.png`
2. Do you have the `gem 'rails_12factor'` gem in your gemfile? https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor
3. In your `config/application.rb`, set `config.assets.version` equal to a float higher than it currently is.  Ie. increment from `1.0` to `1.1`.

Comment: Yeah! A legacy `.slugignore` in project with `*.png`, I removed it and my project worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before with a *.jpg - the only solution I could find was to increment `config.assets.version = '1.0'` in `config/application.rb`, forcing new assets to be generated and all old ones to expire.

Comment: I do, but fails again. The problem was solved editing a misconfigured ".slugignore". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was asking answers for a similar question, then I found this entry, but if it helps in something my solution was so simple, in my project in ruby on rails gave the next error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I had in my project the images in

```
app/assets/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png
```

And I just make another directory named images with the png file inside

```
app/assets/images/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png
```

And that's all, I hope somebody help this simple solution.