# Heroku not generating png files

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll, octopress

I have images stored in a subdirectory as follows,

```
+ public
+ source
  + posts
  + images
     + rss-icon.png
     + post1
       + redsquare.jpg
       + greensquare.png
```

In a post I have the following,

```
![image](/images/post1/redsquare.jpg)  
![image](/images/post1/greensquare.png)
```

On a local server, all three images (*rss-icon, redsquare, greensquare*) render no problems.

But when I deploy to Heroku, the *greensquare.**png*** image does not work. I instead get a `404 Failed to load resource` status.
Both the rss-icon.*png* and redsquare.jpg work fine on the deployed site.

All the suggested solutions I can find apply only to Rails... for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19820917) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15354539).

However I'm not using Rails...

I triple-checked the *gitignore* and *slugignore* files and there is nothing there that would cause this bias.

How can I resolve this? Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Nevermind, found a solution. It was a minor error on my part see answer below. Leaving this here in case useful to someone.

Comment: What is your target url ? Did you have a repository url ?

Comment: My app on the Heroku server launches and is live, everything works except for png images that are in subdirectories as I explain above.

Comment: So what is your url ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out it had nothing to do with the location of the images. Instead it had to do with the **lettercase** of the extension.

My images looked like this, 
[image]

I assumed that the extension was case-insensitive and wrote all my references using lowercase (*png*). But this isn't so! Changing to uppercase fixed the 404 issue.

As a side note, the uppercase PNG images were generated by Microsoft's Snipping Tool,
[image]